# Nginx is ignoring my headers

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I'm working with apache on my local instance and nginx on production.

I have a javascript application that is setting headers in API calls to authenticate the user. It's working fine on local with my apache server. However for some reason, my custom headers are ignored by Nginx.

I tried to add this line in my site configuration:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
```

But it still ignore the headers.
Does anyone know where I should look to bypass this ?

Cheers, 
Maxime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found what was the issue.

My custom headers were `API_USER` and `API_TOKEN`.
There is a directive in Nginx that says **to ignore headers with a '_' in the name**, [more info here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers)

So I've updated my custom headers to `x-api-user` and `x-api-token` and now it's working like a charm !